# eclipse c++ include path

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that is in VIsual Studio but I'm trying to use eclipse instead.  I just want to edit it in Eclipse (because I'm more familiart with) and not really build with it, but I need Eclipse to point me compilations erros.
I've had quite a hard time with eclipse findind the std lib and other headers I needed, but after addind several paths to "Paths ans Symbols" and also to "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." I managed to make it find every inclusion.
Unfourtunately now it finds too many. In particular, when using the `cos` function from math.h in "Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" , Eclipse is findind a `cos` from cmath in"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include".  As I have an explicit `#include <math.h>` and certainly do not mention cmath anywhere, I can't figure out why Eclipse is looking at this file.
At the end of the day I could not understand what is the difference between "Paths ans Symbols" and "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." and could not figure out where I should put the path to the std and where I should put the path to other external header files I must include.

Comment: Other standard headers may include other standard headers which means `<iostream>` could include `<cmath>` for some reason.  Is there a reason you're explicitly using `math.h` instead of `<cmath>`?

Comment: <math.h> is the C version of the include; <cmath> is the C++ version of the include.

Comment: I did not write the code I and I really don't want to (and can't) change something that is working.